# Counting turtles after a chunk of code has executed

Tags: netlogo

In my model currently, I have a monitor on the Interface that counts the total number of turtles (deer in my case) every tick. Is it possible to have another monitor that counts the number of deer after a certain line of code is executed? For example, here's a snippet of code:

```
to catch-fawns-source
let fawn-hunting-rate (fawn-harvest-rate-source)
if any? fawns-on source-patches
[ ask fawns-on source-patches [
if random-float 1.0001 < (fawn-hunting-rate)
[ set harvest (harvest + 1)
set fawn-harvest (fawn-harvest + 1)
   set source-harvest (source-harvest + 1)
 die ] ]
  ]
end
```

In this case, this is where I have fawns being harvested. This code is the same for my male and female adult and juvenile deer. So is there a way I could track my population specifically after that snippet of code (and the other identical ones for the juveniles and adults) is executed?

I'm not sure if I would need any sort of Netlogo extension (if there are any applicable to this) or if I could somehow add in another global variable and lines of code that accomplishes this task.

Thanks for all of your help as always!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get away with another `global` variable that you just update however often you want. For a very simple example, consider this setup:

```
globals [ most-recent-pop-check ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10  
  set most-recent-pop-check count turtles
  reset-ticks
end
```

Here, `most-recent-pop-check` will only be updated when needed, then you can just set a monitor to display that variable. In this example, the value will only change every 25 ticks- see comments for more detail:

```
to go 
  ask turtles [
    ; Turtles may die
    if random-float 1 < 0.25 [
      die
    ]
    ; Throw in some density-dependence to control population size
    if random-float 1 < ( 0.5 * ( 1 - ( count turtles / 500 ) ) )  [
      hatch random 2 + 1
    ]

  ]
  ; If the ticks are not 0, and if the remainder after dividing
  ; the ticks by 0 is 0, update the most-recent-pop-check
  ; variable to reflect the current turtle population.
  if ticks != 0 and ticks mod 25 = 0 [ 
    set most-recent-pop-check count turtles
  ]
  tick
end
```

Of course, in your case rather than having the update occur based on the number of ticks, just have it occur whenever you run the code chunk you're after.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble getting this logic to work for me. For simplicity, let's say I just want to count the number of fawns on the source patches after the code I wrote above has executed. I tried creating a global variable called "fawnsource-after-harvest" and put this line of code: "set fawnsource-after-harvest count fawns-on source patches" after the "die" in the above code. But a monitor with "count fawns-on source-patches" yields the same numbers as a different monitor with "fawnsource-after-harvest". Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: @AmandaV - Unfortunately, without seeing more of your model code nothing comes to mind. Potentially a scheduling issue with when you call `tick`? Not sure, but feel free to update your question with a toy version of your model that replicates the issue you describe- just to make sure, did the example code I posted show the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, you're code updated the population size every 25 ticks, do it did what was expected. I'll post a similar question with a toy version of my model, and maybe that will help figure out the issue. Thanks for your help!